# I have a server I can SSH in. How can I use my laptop (os x) to tunnel through that in a certain browser?

Tags: macos, proxy, tunnel

I have a server I can SSH in. How can I use my laptop (os x) to tunnel through that in a certain browser?

Basically I want to do this:

I have two computers - a server (server running centos) and my home home computer (running os x).

I want to do this:

in OS X tunnel through (ie proxy) my server through to websites (to see sites from the 'eyes' of the server (different country).

Can I login via ssh set up some kind of tunnel then use that as a proxy in a browser?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. In your server install one of these proxy servers:

- 3proxy
- littleproxy
- privoxy
- squid
- tinyproxy

These are package names from Fedora distribution, so use 'yum search proxy' to determine what is available in your version of CentOS.

Then use ssh with port forwarding to connect to your server:

```
ssh -L3128:127.0.0.1:8080 user@host
```

where `8080` - is the port at your server at which the proxy is listening.

Then set your browser to use proxy server at `http://localhost:3128`

Enjoy.